# What are the possible badges to receive on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, badges, stack-overflow-for-teams

There is only a very basic explanation under this [Knowledge Article - Badges](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4396989-badges) which cover only the philosophy of badges.

My first guess was that they are the same as for Stack Overflow, but the functionality is not cloned 1-to-1 with the Teams version so probably some (like moderation badges) are definitely not there.

My second guess was that I can look them up at my profile's dashboard, in the "Next Badge" section, but this list is not complete even for the regular version of the site. Can I get the tag badge there?

Is there any generally available list of badges, that one can receive on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Answer (score 9):

While on your Team, click on the trophy (Achievements) in the top bar. You'll see a link at the very top to "badges". This should have the full list of badges for your Team as well as check marks for the badges that you've already earned.

You can get there directly by using the URL - `https://stackoverflow.com/c/[team name]/help/badges` and replace the [team name] with the name of your team.

Comment: "badges for your Team" The list isn't different between Teams, is it? (Other than which badges you've earned.)

Comment: As opposed to the public list. The list is different between teams and public. 